# Is there any good-practice/rules about when to pass an argument to a method or let the method get the data it needs from the class?

Tags: javascript, class, variables, methods

I mean this more exactly:

```
var MyClass = function(){
    return {
        init: function(a, b, c){
            this.__a = a;
            this.__b = b;
            this.__c = c;
        }
        ,doSomething: function(){
            // when to use this:
            this.__subThingType1();
            // or this?
            this.__subThingType2(this.__a, this.__b, this.__c);
        }
        ,__subThingType1: function(){
            var a = this.__a;
            var b = this.__b;
            var c = this.__c;
            // do dirty things with a, b and c
        }
        ,__subThingType2: function(a, b, c){
            // do dirty things with a, b and c
        }
}​
```

When should I use the type1 or type2? I cannot figure out a rule for this, I find my code that there is a mix between the two, because sometimes I think I will remove that method from this class and put it in a lib.
But is not a good rule, because sometime I leave the method in the class, so a lot of mixing happens.

- Also, the method should return a value or alter the instance variables?

Thanks

Comment: What is the language you use? Specify it in tags so people can help you.

Comment: Language is not relevant, but is javascript with qooxdoo framework, in this example is pure javascript, as not so many people use qooxdoo.

Answer (score 1):

*Store intrinsic data in the instance; pass in extrinsic data as arguments.* For example, your class represents a circle. Store its center and radius as intrinsic data. But your method `intersectionWith` takes an argument `anotherCircle` and returns the area of intersection.

The difference between intrinsic and extrinsic is not always so obvious, but coding is not always obvious. Use your judgement.

More generally, if you're puzzled by this kind of thing, you probably want to learn more about the paradigm of [Object-oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Comment: Interesting, can you explain a little bit more, or with some links, papers/book about the matter? thanks (so, if the properties are in my class as in my example, then I should not pass them as arguments, right?)

Comment: Not necessarily. If they are properties that only get set once, you'd typically provide them to the constructor when you create the instance. But many properties get set and used multiple times during the life of the object, and in that case their values might be supplied as args. Once you get a handle on the OOP concepts, all this stuff will make more sense to you.

Comment: One other thing to be aware of: javascript, because it's prototype-based) is a bit unusual as OOP languages go. Java, Python, Ruby, etc. are more typical. If you're new to OOP, you might want to learn it in the context of one of those.